# Regex / Php - need find words that start with more than 2 capital letters

Tags: php, regex

I dont know anything about regular expressions and thats why I post this question here. Could anyone help me to modify the Regex match below?

It finds words in a string that start with 2 capital letters. I need to modify it to find words that start with 3 capital letters. Thanks.

```
$text = 'text TExt text TEXt teXT texT';
$total_words = preg_match_all('#(?<= )([^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*(?= )|[^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*|[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*)(?= )#', $text, $matches);
echo $total_words;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simplify your regex as,

```
preg_match_all('#(?<!\S)[A-Z]{3}\w*(?!\S)#', $text, $matches);
```

Then count the elements in the returned array.

Answer (score 3):

why not just use this:

`[A-Z]{3}\w*`

Explanation:

`[A-Z]` It will see for a capital letter at the start of the string

`{3}` match exactly 3 times

`\w*` will match any word character zero or more times

demo here :  http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/c6j

Comment: Short and sweet solution!